# How do I select a value in a key:value pair within a list in a column using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a table called payouts, there is a column `stripeResponseData` where the data is in the following structure:

```
{"id":"tr_1BlSHbGQXLV7RqqnHJffUVO0","object":"transfer","amount":39415,"amount_reversed":0,"balance_transaction":"txn_1BlSHbGQXfV7AqqnGi2o7UiY","created":1516239215,"currency":"usd","description":null,"destination":"acct_1BWWAmAzms5xPfV9","destination_payment":"py_1BlSHbAzms5xkfV91RHAOrno","livemode":true,"metadata":{},"reversals":{"object":"list","data":[],"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"url":"/v1/transfers/tr_1BlSHbYQXLV7AqqnHJffUVO0/reversals"},"reversed":false,"source_transaction":null,"source_type":"card","transfer_group":null}
```

Within my SQL SELECT statement, I want to return only the value of the key "destination". How do I write my SQL query?

My desired result of the query:

```
SELECT "stripeResponseData" FROM payouts [...]
```

(where I don't know how to write [...]) should look like the following (assume we have 3 rows with different values on "destination"):

acct_1BWWAmAzms5xPfV9

acct_1AY0phDc9pCDpLR8

acct_1AwG3VL7DXxftOaS

How do I extract that value from the list within the `stripeResponseData` column?

Comment: You have tagged both MySQL and PostgreSQL. What language do you want it in? Is the data stored in a string, or a proper JSON field? We need more information.

Comment: Tag properly!!!!!  MySQL <> Postgres.  Which one is this????

Comment: @muistooshort You should not assume in this case, encourage the user to correct his own post with the correct tag.

Comment: @muistooshort Perhaps it was just pseudocode to demonstrate what he wants. You cannot assume in this case.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistagging. It is postgres. I don't know if the field is JSON or string, I will check and post back! Thanks for the quick feedback.

Comment: @muistooshort The point is not for us to figure out.  The OP should tag properly so we don't need to guess, or worse, give answer to the wrong dbms.  It is a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: @muistooshort No problem. Everyone makes mistakes =)

Comment: @FrankerZ this is a text field, according to `\d tablename`. Would you still be able to describe how the query would differ if a JSON field?

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: @fenomalist If you have access to the data, you should absolutely make that a jsonb field (If you're storing just json in there), so you can take advantage of indexing.

Comment: @fenomalist Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/015d8/6). This query will fetch the ID from `stripResponseData` where the id is a specific id (Probably not very useful, but does show you how to select and query):

```
SELECT data->>'id' FROM stripeResponseData WHERE data @> '{"id":"tr_1BlSHbGQXLV7RqqnHJffUVO0"}';
```

Because you mentioned your data was a string, you need to to type conversions to query/use it correctly. See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e2b32b/4):

```
SELECT data::jsonb->>'id' FROM stripeResponseData WHERE data::jsonb @> '{"id":"tr_1BlSHbGQXLV7RqqnHJffUVO0"}';
```

Per your edit, you can simply query destination in almost the exact same way. This will get all the id's from `stripeResponseData where destination = acct_1BWWAmAzms5xPfV9`:

```
SELECT data::jsonb->>'id' FROM stripeResponseData WHERE data::jsonb @> '{"destination":"acct_1BWWAmAzms5xPfV9"}';
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that you specify the value "tr_1BlSHbGQXLV7RqqnHJffUVO0" in your query. Is there a way to just ask for "id" and get a list of rows with the values? Since all the ids will be different in every row.

Comment: Just don't include any WHERE statement: `SELECT data::jsonb->'id' FROM stripeResponseData`

Comment: Except that [`->` yields a `jsonb` value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE), not the string they're probably looking for.

Comment: Got it. This is super helpful, thanks for being so patient.

Comment: @fenomalist Just use `data::jsonb->>'id'` instead of `data::jsonb->'id'` to select the string, and not a jsonb object. (Thanks @muistooshort)